# Экземпляр какого вида возвращает Inflater

Tags: android

В XML файле определен лэйаут состоящий из нескольких разных вьюшек. Какую конкретно вьюшку вернет этот код?

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.note_item,parent,false);
```

Comment: Что значит состоящий из нескольких View? Приведите разметку

Comment: Он вернёт корневой контейнер вашего лэйаута со всем содержимым или конкретный виджет, если в xml он один и без контейнера.

Answer (score 0):

Возвращает корневой элемент. Проверил методом getClass()

Comment: Эксперименты - это хорошо, но все же не забывайте про документацию. Там прямым текстом указывают что возвращается в обоих случаях https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater#inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)